# Is it possible to use a Snowflake set variable in a sum function?

Tags: function, variables, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table where I would like to sum the values of multiple columns, rather than writing out each column (to save time) I decided to use the set function as below in SnowSQL:

set col = (select listagg(column_name, '+') from information_schema.columns where table_name='tbl_nm');

However, when I then try to run the following statement

select sum($col) from tbl_nm;

I get the below error:

Numeric value 'col1+col2+col3+..' is not recognized

I believe this is because I've set $col as a string so it has the quotations around it. So my question is, is it possible to set a list of columns as a variable in Snowflake SQL to then use in the sum function or any function even?

Edit:
The columns I am using are numeric so I'm expecting to see something like
sum($col) = 10 as this would be equivalent to sum(col1+col2+col3+...)=10

Comment: Could you please add an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Based on provided pseudocode `select sum($col) from tbl_nm;` the goal is to summarize all columns from `tbl_mn`. It could be achieved by unpivoting table and performing `SUM` aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(f.VALUE::NUMBER) AS total
FROM (SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT_KEEP_NULL(*) AS j FROM tbl_mn) AS s
,TABLE(FLATTEN(input => s.j)) f;
```

For input:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tbl_mn(col1 INT, col2 INT, col3 INT)
AS
      SELECT 1, NULL, 2
UNION SELECT 3, 4, 5
UNION SELECT NULL, 6, NULL;
```

Output:

[image]